# Creating a method that creates multiple lists inside a class

Tags: java, list, arraylist, methods

i wanted to know if you can create a method inside a class that can create more than 1 list

```
public class UnidadeSaude {
    private String NomeUnidade;

    public UnidadeSaude() {

    }
    public UnidadeSaude(String NomeUnidade) {
        this.NomeUnidade = NomeUnidade;

    }

     public String getNomeUnidade() {
        return NomeUnidade;
    }
    public void setNomeUnidade(String nomeUnidade) {
        NomeUnidade = nomeUnidade;
    }


    void gravar(String NomeUnidade){
        List<String>  UnidadeSaude = new ArrayList<String>();
        UnidadeSaude.add(NomeUnidade);

    }
     void ler() {
         System.out.print(UnidadeSaude);
     }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you can create more than 1 list in a method. --- [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** in Java, variable names are written in `camelCase` and Classes in `PascalCase`.
This is extremely important to difference between objects and Class references.

**Second:** I think you're trying to write names into a `List` in the `gravar()` method.
You can do it by having a static `List` in the class. You can add them to the list and then print them in the `ler()` method.

```java
public class UnidadeSaude {

    private String nomeUnidade;
    private static List<String> nomeUnidades = new ArrayList();

    public UnidadeSaude() {

    }

    public UnidadeSaude(String nomeUnidade) {
        this.nomeUnidade = nomeUnidade;
    }

    public String getNomeUnidade() {
        return nomeUnidade;
    }

    public void setNomeUnidade(String nomeUnidade) {
        this.nomeUnidade = nomeUnidade;
    }

    void gravar(String NomeUnidade) {
        nomeUnidades.add(NomeUnidade);
    }

    void ler() {
        for (String nome : nomeUnidades) {
            System.out.println(nome);
        }
    }
}
```

**HOWEVER, I don't recommend this!** It doesn't semantically make sense to store multiple objects into a class that represents a single object. You should ideally store them in a List outside that class